# File copy and and increment (iterate) 10000 times

Tags: shell, scripting

I have unix file name - 1241241231.txt

i have to copy and rename with increment counter til 10000, but file name should be of of 10 digits only.

example:
so i have to make copies like  1241241231.txt, 1241241232.txt,1241241233 .... so at 10000 iteration it should be 1241251231.txt

So i need script for this

I have prepared below script , but it works till 9th iteration, but as i want keep  file length of 10 only, so it doesnt work.

```
for i in {1..10000} do
cp 1241241231.txt "124124123$i.txt" ; done
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `seq -f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a simple shell loop:

```
for((i=1241241232; i <= 1241251231; i++)); do cp 1241241231.txt "${i}.txt"; done
```